# SFTP file to Apache2

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have an edit file and would like to use SFTP to upload to Apache2.
Does Ubuntu have SFTP or I need to find one  to install it to machine?

Your information and help is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung

Comment: You did not give much detail. Generally you install ssh on the (apache) server and then ssh in via sftp. There are graphical interfaces for sftp. I like gftp. Be sure to secure your ssh server ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Apache2 and SFTP are different things - Apache2 is a HTTP server while SFTP is a file transfer protocol over SSH.  So I assume your question is "how to transfer file to a server installed with Apache2 with SFTP".

First of all, you need SSH server installed to enable SFTP.  You can verify if SSH server is installed with `dpkg -s openssh-server`.  If it is not installed, please install it `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.  See more information on how to install OpenSSH Server at the [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-sftp-server).

If you have a firewall, remember to open port 22.