# best setup for lamp stack development

Tags: virtualbox, samba, php, lamp, encoding

I currently have ubuntu 14.04 with lamp stack running in virtualbox under win 8.1. I use PhpStorm inside the virtualbox. Virtualbox is running fine except for some flickering and screen refresh issues sometimes.
I think maybe to run PhpStorm under Windows and share my home/project folder with samba. I would do svn/git commits from windows as well
Is it safe from any side effects like wrong file encoding or file rights?

Comment: Sounds just like my PHP development environment. I don't see any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues with using a `VirtualBox` for a LAMP stack.

Since you haven't mentioned any other uses for Ubuntu you have in your `VirtualBox`, might I suggest using a server edition of Ubuntu instead - that way you can save on some resources.

If you need a graphical environment to change configuration files, you can use something like webmin. Which you can install using the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install webmin
```

You can also use `svn` or `git` to push things to LAMP instead of using `samba`, or you could use `sftp` - which would be better. You simply have to install an ssh server, this answer shows you how (note, you might have to change `gedit` to `nano` in several commands if you are using Ubuntu server, if you are using the desktop edition you can follow the guide as-is):

### [How to set up Ubuntu SFTP server?](https://askubuntu.com/a/420679/10857) by [firefly2442](https://askubuntu.com/users/113153/firefly2442)

The best resource to help you begin setting up an ssh service on a host machine using Ubuntu is [OpenSSH Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH). This will allow you to use [SSH File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) (also Secure File Transfer Protocol, or SFTP) to access, transfer, and manage files over SSH.

### Overview of Solution

- On Ubuntu you can setup an `OpenSSH server` on a host machine and a user can then use `ssh` to connect from their client machine to the host machine's server using only a username and password. Note, however, that public key authentication is recommended,

> "Make sure you have a [strong password](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StrongPasswords) before installing an SSH server (you may want to [disable passwords altogether](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#disable-password-authentication))"

- Administrative User Accounts created on the host machine will have sudo privileges, Standard User Accounts created on the host machine will not.

### Setup your OpenSSH Server

To install an OpenSSH server on your host machine:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

### Enable `PasswordAuthentication` in your `sshd_config` file

[To configure your OpenSSH server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring), "first, make a backup of your sshd_config file by copying it to your home directory, or by making a read-only copy in /etc/ssh by doing:"

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults
sudo chmod a-w /etc/ssh/sshd_config.factory-defaults
```

"Once you've backed up your `sshd_config` file, you can make changes with any text editor, for example:"

```
sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Find the line with the phrase `PasswordAuthentication` and make it read:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save your new `sshd_config` file and then restart the host machine's `ssh` service:

```
sudo restart ssh
```

### Setup Port Forwarding on your local router to direct traffic to your OpenSSH server

Note the port your host machine's `ssh` service listens to in the `sshd_config` file and setup your router to forward TCP/UDP traffic aimed at this port to the IP address of your OpenSSH server.

- Typically, you can point your web browser to `192.168.1.1` in order to login to your router and setup port forwarding.

### Connect to your host machine and login to your Administrative User Account with `sudo` privileges

- To open an SFTP shell terminal as `<username>` on the host machine, open a Terminal on your client machine and enter the following command, replacing `123.123.1.23` with your host machine's IP address:

  ```
  sftp <username>@123.123.1.23
  ```

  - If you changed the port number your host machine's OpenSSH server listens to, do:

    ```
    sftp -P <port_number_in_host_machine's_sshd_config_file> <username>@123.123.1.23
    ```
- To open an SSH shell terminal as `<username>` on the host machine, open a Terminal on your client machine and enter the following command, replacing `123.123.1.23` with your host machine's IP address:

  ```
  ssh <username>@123.123.1.23
  ```

  - If you changed the port number your host machine's OpenSSH server listens to, do:

    ```
    ssh -p <port_number_in_host_machine's_sshd_config_file> <username>@123.123.1.23
    ```

### Alternatively, if you simply want to use sftp to visually access the host machine's filesystem (e.g., using Nautilus)

1. Open Nautilus on the client machine
2. Select File > Connect to Server
3. Type: `SSH`
4. Server: Enter your host machine's IP address
5. Port: port number specified in host machine's `sshd_config` file
6. User name: username
7. Password: password

[image]

### Create Standard User Accounts on host machine with limited file permissions outside their home folder

If I understand you correctly, proper file permissions in place on the host machine guarantee that each standard user (without sudo privileges) that you create on the host machine will own their `/home/new_user` directory but have limited permissions with the rest of the directory structure.

- Limited permissions does not mean they are unable to view filenames and directory structure.

Hope that's helpful!