# sFTP setup on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ssh, apache2, sftp, wordpress

My question is necessarily asking for the process of setting up openssh-server, however I want to create an account on my server that has access to specific domain under /var/www/exampledomain.com. Example domain's ownership is www-data:wp-user (wp-user being the user that gives the wordpress installation the ability to do sFTP updates/operations).

So to put it concisely, I want to create a user that is able to have the same rights as wp-user. I essentially want to use sftp-user to modify files that belong to www-data:wp-user.

I've tried many guides like:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/607898/390648
- http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/
  (scroll down to just sFTP)
- https://julienliabeuf.com/setup-cloud-server-sftp/
- A few others...

The process seems stupid simple however I can't seem to achieve my goal. Can this be done at all? Is there a better ownership scheme?

Either way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you can try to create a group like its said in the links given by you, then add in this group all the users that can modify the files which belong to wp-user. finally all the files creates by wp-user need to let the write permission to this group.

Or create a directory where only users who are authorised to modify the files of wp-user can acces to this directory

so the steps are:

```
sudo addgroup ftpaccess //create group ftpacess
sudo adduser paul ftpacess // add user paul to the group ftpacess
```

Or

```
sudo adduser paul -ingroup ftpaccess --shell /usr/sbin/nologin //command in the first link
```

then wp-user will create a file you will change the group owner

```
sudo chgrp ftpacces file
```

Note: you can put your wp-user in the groop ftpaccess then all the users in this group can modify it. (Dont know if its good for security)