# Exact steps for configuring a remote ssh terminal

Tags: ssh, 15.10, gnome-terminal

Could anybody tell me the exact steps to make a secure connection from my server to my external IP address using SSH... I would like to access my Ubuntu server from other places... But securely.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/607898/15811

Comment: Set `PermitRootLogin no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config ` file and use strong password for your personal account  - that's 90% of security for you right there

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer is about SFTP, which is more complicated. Configuring `ssh` server is much easier.

Step 1 :  Install OpenSSH package if not installed

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Step 2 : Add to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Step 3 : Restart sshd service.

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Step 4 : Generate key pair on the computer from where you want to access your machine and copy the public part to your machine:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa your_machine
```

Comment: Ok... Great answer! But is there a certain port I have to allow? Or what is the port so I can access it remotely

Comment: Default port for ssh is 22. You should allow it in your firewall if you use one.

Comment: When you say your machine... Do you mean your machine IP address or the name of it... Because I tried the name of my server and that did not work... How safe is this also... Even with the recent Open SSH Attacks... Could you explain the questions I have to me please?