# Attempt of apt-get install sftp fails with : E: Package 'sftp' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, ssh, sftp

```
magnus@mt-dell:~$ sudo apt-get install sftp
[sudo] password for magnus: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sftp is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sftp' has no installation candidate
```

What to do?

Comment: AFAIK the default sftp client is provided by the `openssh-client` package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the package you want to install is openssh-server.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Source: [How to setup a restricted SFTP server on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu)

Comment: That did the trick. That's what I like about AskUbuntu. Ask a simple question, get a simple answer.

Answer (score 5):

`openssh-client` package contains `sftp` executable. Install using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client
```

Source: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/openssh-client/filelist