# Accessing zfs pool with chroot sftp - User can view files/folders but cannot create

Tags: chroot, sftp, zfs

Here's what I've been trying to do:

- Create a zfs pool that can be accessed through sftp
- Be able to read and write files in the zfs pool through sftp (remotely)
- Create a user who can read/write files in the zfs pool but cannot access any other files on the computer

Here are the two "tutorials" I have been referring to.

- [How to Setup Chroot SFTP in Linux (Allow Only SFTP, not SSH)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup)
- [How to setup a restricted SFTP server on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu)

---

So far, I've gotten the zfs pool set up and I can access it. However, when I try to sftp in using the chroot[ed] account, I can view files but I cannot modify or create new files.

My question is: How do I grant the chrooted user permission to read and write files in the zfs pool?

Interestingly, I can't write to the zfs pool when logged into the computer locally unless I open it as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux Mint...

Adding the user (chrooted user for the sftp access) to the sudo group appears to fix the problem.

[Add a User to a Group (or Second Group) on Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/)