# How to add sftp server on 16.04 Desktop machine?

Tags: 16.04, server, sftp

I have Ubuntu PCs, Windows 10 PCs, Macs, and smartphones. They need to transfer files to and from one particular Ubuntu PC. I would like to do this with standard sFTP clients on the various machines, so I want an sFTP server to run on that Ubuntu PC.

The Ubuntu machines are on 16.04 Desktop.

I am unsure where to start.

I also wonder whether this solution will require more setup or maintenance than an equivalent Samba server. (It seems to me that Microsoft has released several updates which affect Samba connectivity, and at best, require admin actions to re-establish successful sharing.)

Comment: See if [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu#420679) has anything useful for you. I have been using samba on my server. I can mount the drive and forget about it, and easily works between all my machines (linux, windows, Mac, and iPhones)

Comment: The default `openssh-server` package includes an internal `sftp-server` subsystem that "just works" out of the box, in my experience. See for example [How to setup a restricted SFTP server on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420652/how-to-setup-a-restricted-sftp-server-on-ubuntu?)

Comment: Thanks to both of you,  these comments both point to the same resources and same solution (openssh).

Comment: I consider either to be a good answer.  BTW, for me, samba did not work fully when I followed some tutorials. I think that I needed to create user-IDs on the Ubuntu server that match the Microsoft IDs on the Windows 10 PCs, but, didn't try that.  If I ever need more than sFTP, I will try samba again.