# How to allow SSH only with RSA key, and SFTP with password and chroot?

Tags: permissions, ssh, password, sftp

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, I would like to do the following things:

- Enable a non-root admin user with sudo privileges to SSH in to the server using an RSA key (no password)
- Enable selected non-admin users to upload files by SFTP to their own home directory, using a password to log in
- Prevent the non-admin users from gaining access to the rest of the file system

I'm working with a freshly-installed version of Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, so everything is in its default factory condition.

I have read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/420652/426741) and the answers carefully, but I have not been able to find a solution.

I have created a `nonrootadmin` user with sudo privileges.

I have created a `nonadminsftp` user who is a member of the `sftpaccess` group. The `/home/nonadminsftp/` directory looks like this:

```
$ ls -al ~nonadminsftp
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root         root       4096 Oct 25 00:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root         root       4096 Oct 24 22:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 nonadminsftp sftpaccess  220 Sep  1  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 nonadminsftp sftpaccess 3771 Sep  1  2015 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 3 nonadminsftp sftpaccess 4096 Oct 25 00:50 ftp
-rw-r--r-- 1 nonadminsftp sftpaccess  655 May 16 13:49 .profile
```

Their respective entries in `/etc/passwd` are as follows:

```
nonrootadmin:x:1000:1000::/home/nonrootadmin:/bin/bash
nonadminsftp:x:1002:1002::/home/nonadminsftp:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The changes I have made to the `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` file are as follows:

```
PermitRootLogin no
#PasswordAuthentication no

AllowUsers nonrootadmin nonadminsftp
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpaccess
#ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
#ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The solution that I have seen proposes uncommenting 3 of these lines, but I discover that:

- `PasswordAuthentication no` prevents the nonadminsftp user from connecting with a password:

  ```
  $ sftp nonadminsftp@mydomain.com
  Permission denied (publickey).
  Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
  ```
- `ChrootDirectory %h` prevents the nonrootadmin user from connecting at all:

  ```
  $ ssh nonrootadmin@mydomain.com
  packet_write_wait: Connection to 12.34.56.78 port 22: Broken pipe`
  ```
- `ForceCommand internal-sftp` prevents the nonrootadmin from gaining SSH access:

  ```
  $ ssh nonrootadmin@mydomain.com
  This service allows sftp connections only.
  Connection to mydomain.com closed.`
  ```

With these lines commented out:

- nonrootadmin does have SSH access using an RSA key
- nonadminsftp can connect using a FTP client such as FileZilla

BUT:

- nonadminsftp is not `chroot`ed to the `/home/nonadminsftp` directory
- nonrootadmin can log in with a password

What is it that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to look into the `Match User` and `Match Group` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @muru, the following configuration is now working:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no

AllowUsers nonrootadmin nonadminsftp
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match group sftpaccess
# The following directives only apply to users in sftpaccess
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I had previously added `nonrootadmin` to the `sftpaccess` group. After I removed this user from the group...

```
$ sudo gpasswd -d nonrootadmin sftpaccess
$ getent group ftpaccess
ftpaccess:x:1002:nonadminsftp
```

... `nonrootadmin` can now use SSH.