# SSH : User can only access a particular folder in webroot

Tags: server, ssh, remote-access, restricted-access

I would like to create a user which can **only access and administer** a particular folder via **SSH** situated in webroot of the server. Been through many blogs..none of them helped. I am using ubuntu **server 16.04**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible solution is provided with this answer:https://askubuntu.com/a/607898/429130 (if SFTP access is enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two (similar) solutions for your problem:

1. SSH Chroot jail

   When the user logs in with ssh he will chroot automatically in the directory you've configured and will not be able to exit it (jail)
2. SFTP

   I've used [mysecureshell](https://github.com/mysecureshell/mysecureshell) on several occasions when needed to provide access to webroot directory. MySecureShell is basically a wrapper around chroot so more or less it will do the same.