# After update to Ubuntu 17.10, my mounted drive not working

Tags: permissions, mount, 17.10

My system got updated from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04. At the time all things were working well. But after that in a few days update to Ubuntu 17.10 was also available so I updated it.

After the update to Ubuntu 17.10, my mounted network folders are not working now.
When I click on a mounted folder it gives me permission issue message as displayed in this image:

[image]

My `fstab` file content as given below

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1b55458c-51f1-43e1-9abe-5c0418094669 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=184E-A348  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=a05e7035-b2e2-45e5-9bcd-39204a0f4503 none            swap    sw              0       0



//177.10.10.123/DEV6 /home/nilesh/DEV6 cifs uid=nilesh,rw,username=usernamehere,password=pwdhere,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

I have tried by adding `vers=1.0` in `fstab` lines mounting shares but it's still not working.

What is the solution?

---

I have also tried to execute 'sudo nautilus' command but getting below error

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:9087): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Try the solution given by this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/46185/39869

Comment: thats not work for me and thats all very old posts may be that reason for not working. Thanx for your comment, is there any other way.

Comment: @EmersonHsieh is there any solution?

Comment: Can you run "$ stat /home/nilesh/DEV6" and tell me the owner of the directory found  in the Uid: section - Like this --> Uid: (1234 / owner)

Answer (score 0):

The cifs option for version 1 is `vers=1.0`, not `ver=1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mount options you don't have and need.

Firstly, you need the `user` option to allow non-superuser to use the `/etc/fstab` defined mount point/rules.  This is an option listed in `man fstab 5`:

```
   The fourth field (fs_mntops).
          This  field  describes  the  mount  options  associated with the
          filesystem.

          It is formatted as a comma-separated list of options.   It  con‐
          tains at least the type of mount (ro or rw), plus any additional
          options appropriate to the filesystem  type  (including  perfor‐
          mance-tuning options).  For details, see mount(8) or swapon(8).

          Basic filesystem-independent options are:

          ... 

          user   allow a user to mount

          ...
```

Secondly, since this is a CIFS mount, you need to know what CIFS protocol version you're using on the share server.  If you're using any Windows share pre-Windows 2006, or an old Samba share that speaks an old and obsolete protocol, you need to also have `vers=1.0` in the mount options to tell it to use a CIFS share.  However, if that gives you "Invalid Argument" errors, then you should try using `vers=2.0`.  If that doesn't work, then use `vers=3.0` and drop `sec=ntlm` (which solved my issues with Windows 2016 share mounts).