# How to mount a windows drive in ubuntu

Tags: mount, disk

We have a Windows Dell Server with a corrupt RAID array.
We ran Ubuntu from a USB stick and managed to copy some files from the C drive, but the D drive (DATA) we cant mount or access, I guess its to corrupt to do that, but are there any way to come around this problem , we are not precisely Ubuntu experts, we just are trying to save a couple of files that where locked in the previous back up. 
Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access my Windows partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148474/how-do-i-access-my-windows-partition)

Answer (score 5):

Check the name of the partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If the name of the windows ntfs partition is for example sda3:

```
sudo mkdir /media/OS 
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sda3 /media/OS
```

Comment: You need to disable fast boot in windows as well

Comment: @Panther True !!

Comment: Thank you, but I cant access Windows on it, all I need to do is copy files but I cant access the drive at all, I cant mount it either. I can see the drive , its in NTFS, maybe that got something to do with it?

Comment: Edited my answer. To mount ntfs you need to add some things.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 18.10:

1. First install `cifs-utils` using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
   ```
2. Now run following command:

   ```
   sudo mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/network-drive-folder /mnt -o username=testuser,vers=1.0
   ```

   Here, my source (to be mounted) is - `//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/network-drive-folder` and destination (where it is to be mounted) is `/mnt` (system provided mounting point). 
   `testuser` is a username which has access to windows network drive. And last but very crucial `vers=1.0`. For someone `vers=2.0` or `vers=3.0` also work as per system stack.