# How do I SFTP into my Ubuntu's 2nd & 3rd Drives?

Tags: filesystem, sftp

I apologize as I'm rather new and learning as I go. I have an Ubuntu PC acting as a server, to which I can connect via SFTP just fine through WinSCP on my Win10 PC. I want to access it's 2nd & 3rd HDDs, which contain all the data I'm SFTPing into for in the first place.

I don't know how to even go about trying to access these other drives (called "z" & "x") and typing in a manual directory gives me a "directory doesn't exist" error. I don't know how it should be formatted in the first place, either.

I have also tried installing Samba & using the "sharing" option for the two drives, but the Ubuntu PC doesn't show up as a shared device.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: There are no drive letters ("z" or "x") in linux. The drives and their partitions are exposed as block devices in the `/dev/` folder. If they are automatically mounted, you can find them in `/media/<yourUsername>/``. If not, you'll have to mount them manually (see e.g. [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071759/how-to-mount-a-windows-drive-in-ubuntu)).

Answer (score 1):

I knew this would be a dumb question. After looking for over an hour, I stumbled on a comment somewhere that said secondary drive folder locations are found in the /media directory. And there they where!