# automount smb share customization

Tags: 12.10, xorg, smb

as a new linux user, used Ubuntu 12.10, I tried several tweaks with the SMB shares. I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) to mount permanently 4 SMB shares from my local NAS.

To resume, I :

- edit /etc/fstab
- added a line like :

  ```
  //servername/sharename /media/windowsshare cifs credentials=/home/ubuntuusername/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
  ```
- created a credentials file for security reasons in my home folder (explained in the tutorial)

  ```
  ~/.smbcredentials
  ```

It work perfectly, they are automounted on each reboot, but when I logon, I all the time get 4 file explorer open with each share.

It is possible to avoid these file explorer window to be opened on every reboot ? I guess it's related to X or via a explicit deny or these graphical mount, but I don't have any clues on how to proceed

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mounting the SMB shares in `/media/windowsshare` mount it as `/mnt/windowsshare`. You will have to create the folders there first and then edit the `/etc/fstab`. Make a copy of `/etc/fstab` before editing just to be safe.

Then the shares won't open in Nautilus on their own.

Note: `/media` is for computer generated mounts such as when you plugin an USB drive. `/mnt` is for admin to mount things manually or by editing `fstab` etc. See [Why have both /mnt and /media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media)

Comment: Works perfectly ! I knew that /mnt is mostly used for "temporary" mounted devices but I thought it was the only difference with /media.

Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. `/media` is for computer generated mounts such as when you plugin an USB drive. `/mnt` is for admin to mount things manually or by editing `fstab` etc. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media .