# How to select mount points for Windows partitions?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, mountpoint

Can someone give me some criterias on how to select mounting points for ubuntu installation?

At the moment Windows 7 is my main OS on the pc and the 250GB hdd memory is allocated this way:

```
C:/ -Win7 OS
D:/ -Everything else(games,music,photos etc)
Other partition Ext4 -ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

And now I want to make ubuntu as my primary OS but I don't know how to proper select mounting points to use it to my advantage.

Example:

```
1st partition Ext4 for ubuntu- that will be set on `/`
2nd partition Ext4 for games,photos
3rd partition NTFS for Windows 7
4th partition NTFS for windows games.
```

So where to set my 2nd partition's mounting point to save my other things?

```
/home
```

or something else?

Comment: You can install linux on (/) 1 partition, win7 2 partition, and data 3 partition. Linux can access to 3 partition so you can use data contained in 3 partition. On the other hand, you can create a folder in 3 partition called linux for example, and mount directly this folder as your home. Remember that you need install ntfs-3g in linux for access to NTFS partitions.

Comment: "Remember that you need install ntfs-3g in linux for access to NTFS partitions."- I am using pysdm for accesing ntfs with full permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd ext4 partition can be `/home`. It will contain your users' data such as photos and music, but it will not contain any Linux games. This is because Ubuntu has its own system of placing application or program files in special places within its system. There is no way to install games in `/home' or any other partitions or folders of your choice.  See [Linux Filesystem Tree Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview) for details.

**You have three choices for the NTFS partitions:**

**One,** Create two folders under `/media` such as `/media/Win7` and `/media/WinData` and mount the partitions there. `/media` is where the partitions are mounted when you select them in the Nautilus. The advantage of mounting the Windows partitions in `/media` is that they remain available on the left panel of Nautilus as drive icons. However, if you don't want the Windows partitions to appear with drive icons in Nautilus, then consider option **two** below.

**Two** Create two folders under `/mnt` such as `/mnt/Win7` and `/mnt/WinData` and mount the partitions there. If you do this, the partitions won't appear as special icons in Nautilus. Both these options are explained in more details at [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions).

**Three** This is essentially the free for all option. For example, you may create two folders `/Win7` and `/WinData` under `/` and mount the partitions there.

In terms of functionality in Nautilus, **two** and **three** are the same. **Two** may be preferred for historical reasons and keeping the `/` root less cluttered. In both cases you can create bookmarks in Nautilus to easily access the mount points.

There seems to be a debate about which of this three is right. See [Why have both /mnt and /media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media) for some answers.

Comment: First of all thank you for your first link, it didn't occured in my head to search for filsystem tree overview.