# How to properly add new hard drivers to existing Ubuntu system?

Tags: 13.10, hard-drive

I thought Ubuntu will automatically add new hard drives so I only attached them and booted the system. Ubuntu indeed added them but they look like USB flash drives and I can unmount them.

[image]

How can I add them in a way they they look like a system partitions and not like some USB flash drives?

Comment: It makes sense, doesn't it? You can unmount whatever you want, but not a disk you work on. Are the hard drives external or internal? I have the same situation with my 2TB external USB disk. Nothing to worry about mate. I don't think it is possible to make them system partitions unless you boot from them.

Comment: @Xylo They are internal and each partition is recognised as it's own disk. This can be done as I've done it on my old machine long, long time ago but forgot how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this point Ubuntu doesn't make a real difference between hard drives and USB sticks...
Storage device is storage device. Every partition (except the root partition) is treated the same way, be it on a internal HDD or an CD or whatever. They all mounted on their own mountpoint and can all be unmounted.

I guess you're looking forward to something like the "My Computer" on Windows. Without some alternative file browser I don't think you'll have any success in this. I even doubt there is one...

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media) might in some way reference to your's.