# Two HDD partitions with the same name result in uncertain directories

Tags: 14.04, directory, reboot, partitioning

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a machine that has a lot of hard drives plugged into it. These hard drives have partitions with old OS's which have a lot of key data that I use often.

The problem is, I have 2 partitions with the same name, "Main Drive" and "Main Drive". Ubuntu, to differentiate between them, renames one drive to "Main Drive1", while keeping the other just "Main Drive".

The problem is, every time I restart Ubuntu, it chooses randomly which partition to rename. As a result, any bookmarks or directories that I have in those partitions, do not work, and have to be reconfigured every time I reboot.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: just rename one of the partitions

Comment: I saw that coming lol

Comment: ;D why not? You could look at your mountall.sh

Comment: A safe way to mount drives is to edit your `/etc/fstab` and include UUIDs instead of names like `/dev/sda3`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LittleByBlue is correct that that is the easiest method. I myself would rename both to "Main Drive 1" and "Main Drive 2".

> The problem is, every time I restart Ubuntu, it chooses randomly which partition to rename.

That is normal for USB mounting. We use UUIDs to fix this problem. [See the wiki UsingUUID about this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID) (these UUIDs are edited into  /etc/fstab and you can get UUIDs per partition with `sudo blkid`)

---

You can also mount one of them in another location. Those disks probably all mount in /media and we also have /mnt as mountpoint (see [Why have both /mnt and /media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media) for the difference). Mounting is done in /etc/fstab.

Comment: So I tried to rename them in gparted. But after I unmounted them, I couldn't remount them due to an error: "Unable to read the contents of this file system!" Any ideas?

Comment: if NTFS you probably need to install `ntfsprogs`

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without one of them being displayed in "Devices" section, just mount it somewhere in `/etc/fstab`
The name that you see is written inside file system and can't be altered by udev rules. But you can make one of the disks mount totally unreadable on boot, and make it readable after the GUI booted. Mount options or udev rules can help in this.
You can although use udev to run a renaming script every time disk is mounted and unmounted, but I'd recommend against it - it just feels bug-prone.
Anyway, study [udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).