# Mounting a drive as a directory: Am I doing it right?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, mount

Reinstalled Ubuntu on a new disk, and thought that instead storing my stuff in /home, I plan to attach my old home drive as a directory and basically replace my xdg-folders with simlinks of the old directories on the old drive.

Here is the mount options for that drive:
[image: Mount Options]

are these settings good? The only thing I've removed from the mount options is `x-gvfs-show` which made the file system appear as a mountable drive in the dash and Nautilus (which I didn't wanted), I've also changed the filesystem type from `auto` to `ext4` since that's the correct format of that file system.

Any thoughts? I'm also curious if the `/mnt` is good for permanently mounting that drive in.

Comment: See the original answer part of the accepted answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), /mnt is used for manual mounts. While you can mount it anywhere, if you want to follow convention, you would mount the drive to a folder in /media. This is where Ubuntu by default will place secondary drives at install time.

You however, according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389980) anything mounted from /mnt will not appear there so you may be inclined to break this convention.

Drives that are listed in /etc/fstab will also reside in /media.
As for your mounting options, the defaults are okay.

[Potential Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191405/do-you-need-to-specify-the-defaults-option-in-fstab)

Comment: Yes, I did that. I want to use that drive as a media storage. My question is that is it safe to change the mounting options to `default`

Comment: The sources I found say `/mnt` is not meant for permanent mounts.

Comment: Melebius, phone typo s/is/isn't. I reworded it.

Comment: Negirno, using the default mounting option would result the same outcome as not changing any options. Its a placeholder to avoid empty values, please refer to the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The location `/mnt` is meant for manual, temporary mounts. The location `/media` is used for automatic, temporary mounts.

Permanent mounts can be mounted anywhere and you should put them where the *contents* should be. The Linux filesystem is meant to hide such “implementation details” like the physical location of data.

So if your disk is meant to contain videos, mount it under `/home/<user>/videos`. If it is meant to hold webpages, mount it under `/var/www`. And so on.

I won’t comment the options you selected. If they work, just keep them. If not, correct them or possibly ask a specific question.

### References

- http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/mnt.html

Comment: The drive which I mounted is my old home partition and it contains all my documents, videos, music, etc. symlinked to the appropriate XDG directories. I want to use that drive as a general personal data holder, opposed to a separate home because I don't want old configuration files to clash with newly installed systems (I reinstall from scratch). Also I have the minor problem of not be able to moving things to the trash in the mounted drive. I can SHIFT-DEL or `rm`, however.

Comment: In that case, I would mount it to `/home/<user>/old` (or `/home/_old` if there are multiple meaningful user accounts) or – if you have some free time and possibility to backup – try to merge the contents of home partitions (mostly copy the new one over the old one) and then mount it as the home partition.