# How to enable snap app permissions to read files on a secondary HDD?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, snap

I have a secondary internal hard drive to store files. However, Snap programs in Ubuntu do not have the permissions to open the files on the secondary hard drive. To open files with certain Snap apps, I have to copy them first to the primary Ubuntu drive to access them.

**Desired solution:** How do I enable Snap access to contents on my secondary internal HDD as if it was my main hard drive with full permissions.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: I'd love to hear how you solved this issue. Thanks.

Comment: This should work: https://snapcraft.io/docs/raw-volume-interface

Comment: Depends upon the program, and depends where the second hard drive is mounted.  For example: Acces to /media is fairly straightforward, but access to /var/foo is not.