# 1TB Secondary Hard Drive keep unmounting when reboot or log out Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: mount, kubuntu, hard-drive, backup, 22.10

I get this problem where my secondary HD keeps unmounting whenever I reboot my PC or log out. I know this is the issue because when Deja backup notification pop up saying `backup failed`.

I have to open Dolphin and see my seondary HD is unmount

[image: error message]

**Update**

Install `Disks Gnome` from Discover.

I do not have gear symbol when I click on my Secondary Drive.

[image: Secondary Drive]

Comment: Is the hard drive an external device? If so, have you checked the power profiles for the port that is being used?

Comment: I have secondary HD slot in my laptop. I do not plug the HD in as USB @matigo

Comment: In the Disks utility, you can edit mount options - check auto mount is selected there. Further information here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/271516/is-there-a-program-to-mount-all-of-my-drives-automatically

Comment: @Will I dont' have gear symbol

Comment: Is it because the `1 TB Secondary` not format to NTFS? if I reformat to NTFS, Linux wont write to it automatically? I would have to modify the permissions as well unless I am wrong

Comment: If the disk is not being used by Windows, then NTFS would be wholly unnecessary. As it stands, there is not enough information to answer your question. Could you [edit] it to include: (1) the brand/model of the machine (2) the power profile for the port that the drive is connected to? With this, it may be possible for someone to let you know how to ensure that the drive remains accessible to the hardware 

Comment: Did you add entry to mount in fstab? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207427/how-to-enable-full-permissions-on-internal-secondary-hdd & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: @matigo I figure out the solution. I will post the answer within 1 hour