# How to edit files on other NTFS partitions

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, disk

So I just dual boot the latest version of Ubuntu 23.04 with Windows 10

And I have a total of 4 partitions 1 for Windows 2 other and 1 for Ubuntu I can't edit files on the two other 2 partitions like delete or moving something there from my Ubuntu OS

[image]

Please tell me if is there any solution to this or I just have to open my Windows OS in order to edit files in these partitions

Result of **sudo -l parted**

```
 Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB   367MB   fat32                                 boot, esp
 2      368MB   209GB   209GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 3      209GB   210GB   597MB   ntfs                                  hidden, diag
 4      210GB   210GB   564MB   ntfs                                  hidden, diag
 5      210GB   577GB   367GB   ntfs                                  msftdata
 6      577GB   893GB   316GB   ntfs                                  msftdata
 7      893GB   901GB   8590MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
 8      901GB   1000GB  98.8GB  ext4
```

[image]

dev/sda5 which is showing mounted but i dont know how to access it

Comment: Turn off fast startup/hibernation in Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: already done didnt work @oldfred

Comment: Read `man mount mount.ntfs-3g ntfsfix`. Try `sudo mount -o remount,rw _device_ _mountpoint_`. The NTFS volumes must be mounted Read/Write. BTW, you did boot into Windows and do a full Windows shutdown, right?

Comment: Note that NTFS partition permissions cannot be changed. Windows does not support permissions. You set a default set of permissions with the mount command or if permanent drive, the line in fstab or default settings from an auto mount.

Comment: @waltinator not working and yes i did shutdown windows correctly

Comment: @oldfred i just want to know is there any way to edit file from my ubuntu os or not if yes hten please give me direct steps becuase i am not very pro in ubuntu i am just using ubuntu becuase windows 10 work very slow in my laptop and it also has many wifi problem which i dont have to face in ubuntu

Comment: Not sure what issue now is? If Windows fast start up has not set hibernation flag, if NTFS does not need chkdsk from Windows, the Linux NTFS driver works well with NTFS partitions. Double check settings again. And re-review links in first comment on how to shut down Windows.  Also if old system and Windows is slow, you may be better off with a light weight flavor of Ubuntu. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie I use Kubuntu which is a mid-weight flavor.

Comment: @oldfred I don't think this is about any of the issues you mentioned above. Because i have done everything on Windows 10 like chkdsk etc and i really dont think that this is a distro problem one more thing is that i can watch videos that are oin that partition even copy from them but i cant paste anything there or delete anything there that is the real problem mounting is not an issue

Please help me if you have any solution

Comment: How are you mounting it? Read only is typically the only way Linux NTFS driver will mount NTFS if hibernation flag is set, which fast startup also sets. Post in question above the one line from this that is the NTFS mount. `mount`.  You can unmount with umount command & try manual mount. Manually Mount NTFS
https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072

Comment: @oldfred i have a problem i followed this and the parttion just dissapear i cant no longer see it in the other location but the funny thing is that one other partition which i didnt use the command for now i can delete things from there but my dev/sda5 i cant no longer see please help

Comment: When you unmount it, then it will disappear until you remount it. Post the mount command lines of only thel NTFS partitions. And post `sudo parted -l` Are you mounting with fstab or manually by clicking in file browser?

Comment: mounting it with manually clicling on file browser @oldfred

Comment: @oldfred please see edit i also added disks screenshot of dev/sda5

Comment: After clicking on partition, in terminal run `mount` and post just the lines for mount of your NTFS partitions.

Comment: @oldfred Thank man/woman you solved my problem so ubuntu created a mnt folder on ubuntu parttion from where i can access my dev/sda5 after mounting it and can also edit files Thanks you very much

Comment: What actually worked? And if internal drives better to add to fstab, so on every reboot it is automatically restore. Many posts on example fstab entries for NTFS partitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145590/discussion-between-imposter-and-oldfred).