# How to add a second disk to shared space?

Tags: hard-drive

I have two disks on my laptop (ASUS FX-505DT), which has two disks: SSD (256 Gb) and HDD (1 Tb). I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and can write only to disc with OS. But on my side panel i see icon of my HDD and can open it and read. How can i setup my system to write on it too?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6WQt.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following information: How is the 1TB HDD formatted? Do you see any errors if you manually mount the HDD from the terminal? If so, copy and paste into the question. How do you want to use the HDD once it is mounted? In the men time you may want to read about the file `/etc/fstab` and how to use it.

Comment: Is Windows fast startup off? Windows may turn it back on with updates. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation