# Data in NTFS partitions not shown in Ubuntu

Tags: ntfs

I am dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04, both OS's are on a SSD. And three NTFS partitions on a 1TB HDD as storage for both OS's. These NTFS
partitions could be accessed from both systems until recently. But now Ubuntu does not show data in those drives. Disk utility app shows the entire 1TB HDD as unallocated space. But from Windows all data can be seen.

Please help me to recover those days from Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu will never mount tainted ntfs partitions. So those could be hibernated when you enter Ubuntu or contain errors the Microsoft choose to ignore to inform you about. From Ubuntu unmount if mounted and do a manual mount. It should show the error you need to fix. Edit the  q with the results from  the mount if needed.

Comment: Fast Startup which sets hibernation flag or hibernation. Also Windows 11 may default to bitlocker. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks.I used the following command and now it's working again  mount /mnt/drive_location_here