# I installed Ubuntu in dual boot with windows but it doesn't show the freespace of 80GB partition that I made in windows,help?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I made a 80GB partition in windows in the C disk but in the Ubuntu installator I can't find that, it shows me only a freespace partition with 0 MB. Installator neither detects windows to check the option of install along with windows boot manager.

Also the partition is GPT format and static (not dynamic), both systems start in UEFI.

I already deactivated BitLocker in the C disk viewing possible solutions, also I deactivated fast startup.

Partitions shown in Windows (the free espace of 78GB is what I want to view in Ubuntu, created from C disk):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6AlS.jpg)

Partitions shown in ubuntu installator:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPrTg.jpg)

Output of executing fdisk command:

```
Disco /dev/loop0: 2,54 GiB, 2731876352 bytes, 5335696 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop1: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop2: 63,28 MiB, 66355200 bytes, 129600 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop3: 240,61 MiB, 252301312 bytes, 492776 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop4: 346,33 MiB, 363151360 bytes, 709280 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop5: 304 KiB, 311296 bytes, 608 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop6: 49,84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/loop7: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/nvme0n1: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectores
Disk model: INTEL HBRPEKNX0202A                    
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: dos
Identificador del disco: 0x00000000

Dispositivo    Inicio Comienzo      Final   Sectores Tamaño Id Tipo
/dev/nvme0n1p1               1 4294967295 4294967295     2T ee GPT


Disco /dev/nvme1n1: 27,25 GiB, 29260513280 bytes, 57149440 sectores
Disk model: INTEL HBRPEKNX0202AO                    
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disco /dev/sda: 29,31 GiB, 31466323968 bytes, 61457664 sectores
Disk model: DataTraveler 2.0
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de etiqueta de disco: gpt
Identificador del disco: A0891D7E-B930-4513-94D9-F629DBD637B2

Dispositivo Comienzo    Final Sectores Tamaño Tipo
/dev/sda1         64  9613459  9613396   4,6G Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/sda2    9613460  9623527    10068   4,9M Sistema EFI
/dev/sda3    9623528  9624127      600   300K Datos básicos de Microsoft
/dev/sda4    9625600 61457600 51832001  24,7G Sistema de ficheros de Linux


Disco /dev/loop8: 45,93 MiB, 48160768 bytes, 94064 sectores
Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamaño de sector (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamaño de E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Output of partitons command in Ubuntu:

```
S.ficheros                  Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
tmpfs                         763M    11M  753M   2% /run
/dev/sda1                     4,6G   4,6G     0 100% /cdrom
/cow                          3,8G   343M  3,4G   9% /
/dev/disk/by-label/writable    25G   4,4M   23G   1% /var/log
tmpfs                         3,8G      0  3,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5,0M   8,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3,8G   520K  3,8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                         763M   168K  763M   1% /run/user/999
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Ubuntu cannot use Windows partitions. Is 80GB actually NTFS?  Leave the 80GB as unformatted unallocated free space. Also make sure Windows fast start up is off which sets hibernation flag. If not the installer may not see the NTFS partitions.

Comment: In every guide to make this you have to create partitions, so I created a 80GB partition in windows, and according to disk properties is NTFS, GPT and static (not dynamic). I added information in my question like photos and console outputs if you can help me please.

Comment: Windows cannot create Linux partitions, never seen any instructions that say to create a Windows formatted partition for Linux. You do show an ext4 partition which Ubuntu can use. But Windows partitions are not shown. Do you have Windows fast startup or bitlocker on? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state

Comment: I said in in the question, yes, I had bitlocker on but I deactivated it and tried again but nothing changed, also I deactivated the fast startup option, futhermore I tried to install it shiuting down windows with shift but none of that worked

Comment: GPT as I said and according to the disk C properties

Comment: What happens when you select sda and hit the +?  Does the installer offer to make a new partition, allowing you to change the default size (probably shows a  max of 80G)?

Comment: It won't let me, sda according to a text in the ubuntu installator is the USB drive, futhermore it has too low space to be the disk. See my second photo in the question. Anyways there are more details about it in the console outputs that I put above.

Comment: Nmve is the disk but I'm afraid of lose data creating someing on it, because the + button is not enabled and it asks me to create a new table of partitions and I don't know what that could do.