# external SSD not detected

Tags: ssd

Hope someone can help here, PC can see external SSD in Windows but not in Ubuntu.
I tried:
sudo fdisk -l
But it does not list out the SSD. I disconnect/connect again there is no difference in the output either when I do:
ls /dev/ | grep sd
Format is NTFS and tried as well with exFAT
Appreciate any suggestion

Comment: It might not be an sd device, Try sudo blkid and see the whole list of partitions.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware & SSD firmware? Is Windows fast startup/hibernation flag set? That locks Windows partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &

Comment: Search with your favorite search engine "ubuntu sharing NTFS with Windows". Your problem is how Windows leaves the disk, not Ubuntu.