# NVMe SSD can't be selected as boot option

Tags: partitioning, uefi, ssd, bios, nvme

I was using my windows pc all and well but suddenly windows stopped working. I have a usb bootable Ubuntu and with this I wanted to extract my files before formatting the SSD completely but for some reason, it is not listed in `Disks` and does not show it on `lsblk` or `sudo fdisk -l`. I opened the BIOS options to check what is going on and it is listed as you can find from the attached file: [image]

In BIOS:
I have disabled the secure boot
SATA mode is AHCI
I have switched Legacy OS/UEFI OS modes back and forth nothing is changed. What should I do to reach this ssd and its files, ubuntu commands are also accepted.

**EDIT:**

I have installed windows to my HDD, I can see it in device manager as **Standard NVM Express Controller**, I updated the driver but still the same condition. I can disable or uninstall too. I just want it to be visible whether from windows or ubuntu usb to be able to format it and use it. It is also not visible in disk management (as well as disks in ubuntu)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems to me an hardware problem in the ssd. Try it on another pc... if it still does not work it is that for sure....

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & NVMe firmware? And did you leave Windows fast startup on which sets hibernation flag & prevent Linux NTFS driver from seeing the NTFS partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460440/my-other-drive-still-has-windows-files-after-installation-made-sure-not-to-dual & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation