# Permissions and secnd hard disk drive

Tags: permissions

I put in a new ssd and installed 22.04 ubuntu. I have my HDD as a second drive. I have photos and recorded camera videos on the second drive or HDD. I try to access them but it comes up as I am not the owner and do not have permission. I have tried many solutions, but it seems the videos and photos have to be in the ubuntu filing system.I could not even transfer a photo or video into ubuntu system on the SSD drive. Please how do I fix the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable full permissions on internal secondary HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207427/how-to-enable-full-permissions-on-internal-secondary-hdd)