# Where to mount HDD partitions? Who is the owner?

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, ssd, chmod

The primary SSD in Ubuntu is mounted at FileSystems root.

Where do I mount the additional HDD that I have in my system? Is `/media/<NewDirectory>` the right place?

Who should be the owner of this new partition?

Comment: See answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media).

Answer (score 0):

Yes additional drive usually goes under `/media` and the owner is usually  the same user that will need to use it (and it's often the user that mounted the drive).

For example if you are logged as *user123* and plug a USB stick, nautilus will mount your drive under `/media/user123/<usb-stick-name>/` and you will be the owner of that folder.

However you're free to change that if you really need to. For example if one of your drive is only usefull to one of your system service/appliation you can make that service the only owner of the mounted drive. Or if you have a drive that you want to share between all users you can make it owned by a group of users.